# Poring Over the Numbers: A Hidden Message

Tags: password, encoded-message, calculation-puzzle

I thank my lucky stars I'm able to write this to you. I spent a hefty percentage of my remaining cash at the courier's office and I want to underscore the importance of this communique. If a man comes at you exclaiming that he's found my magic hat, do *not* hash out our plan in response to his inquiries.

I need you to come here, plus I need the contents of our safe. The combination is a five-digit number encoded in this letter. It can be deduced by poring over the numbers with simple arithmetic. Please come quickly.

Sincerely,

Fatima

---

**Knowing that all five digits of the safe combination are unique, can you deduce the combination?**

Comment: Simply brilliant. Love it, Coto! It's difficult, but in a way that is logically progressed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The words in the message

> stars, percentage, cash, at, and, underscore, at, exclaiming, hat, hash, plus

correspond to

> characters `*%$@&_@!^#+` on the top row of an [American keyboard](http://www.goodtyping.com/teclatUSok.png)

which are

> "capitalized" versions of the symbols `85427-2163=` on the corresponding keys

which gives the answer

> 83264 when evaluated arithmetically. This has 5 distinct digits, as confirmation.

Thanks to @No. 7892142 for noticing symbols I'd missed that fix my answer.

---

Old answer:

The words in the message

> stars, percentage, cash, exclaiming, hash

correspond to

> symbols *%$!# on the top row of an American keyboard

which further correspond to

> the digits 85413 on those keys.

Comment: Should have at least mentioned the word "English" in the message then, I think..

Comment: Super quick! I like it. But I don't have a matching PC equipment :c)

Comment: Concerning the new answer...what about "exclaiming" and the second "at"?

Comment: @No.7892142 Thanks, I'd forgotten about the exclamation and missed the 'at'. I've added those and I hope this is now the right answer.

Comment: The new answer is indeed the correct one. Good show. ;)